# using gsub with a column on a dataframe

Tags: r

I had a little problem with a column in my dataframe.

```
dat$Dx1
#[1]  F20.0 F13.2 F31.3 F33.1 F06.2 F34.0 F41.2 F31.7 F32.2 F41.0 F23.0
#[12] F33.1 F20.0 F41.0 F41.2 F34.1 F20.0 F20.0 F60.3 F32.1 F06.2 F20.0
#[23] F06.3 F41.2 F41.2 F20.0 F33.2 F42.2 F32.1 F20.0 F20.0 F20.0 F20.0
```

This is an example of the column. I want to erase all the "decimals" (they are not exactly decimals because they are characters) using `gsub()`, but when I write and run the code for all the ".1", ".2" like...

```
dat$Dx1 <- gsub(".1","",dat$Dx1)
```

It makes a mess like:

```
 #[1] "F"   "3"   "F"   "3"   "6"   "4"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "3"  
 #[12] "3"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "4"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "6"   "F"  
 #[23] "6"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "3"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "F"   "F"
```

I just want to erase it like F20.0 >> F20 in all the elements

Maybe I'm writing a bad code, can someone help me please?

Comment: You need to use `\\.` or `[.]`.  See ?regex.  What is `gp()`?  You could just do `sub("\\..*", "", dat$Dx1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to escape the `.` with either `\\.` or `[.]`. See `?regex`. So the call becomes

```
sub("\\..*", "", dat$Dx1)
```

For example,

```
x <- c("F20.0", "F13.2", "F31.3", "F33.1")
sub("\\..*", "", x)
# [1] "F20" "F13" "F31" "F33"
```

We can use `sub()` instead of `gsub()` since we are always matching the first (and only) occurrence of `.`.